# Solve triangle given point and angle

Tags: trigonometry

Very basic question, but I'm having difficulty finding an answer. It wasn't listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles), or on $\approx 20$ other sites I looked at.  I don't know how to solve a right triangle if I'm only given a point and angle, like so:

[image: B is 13 degrees, Point corresponding to A is (-1, 2)]

Here, the bottom of the triangle is on the x-axis.

Comment: The coordinate is in reference to the origin of a 2D grid.

Comment: If it is the $x$-axis. then the little side has length $2$, so you know all the angles and a side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you to assume that the right angle is at $(-1,0)$?

If so, then $\tan 13^\circ = {2\over {\rm horizontal\ leg}}$, so this can be solved for the horizontal leg, about 8.66. That gives the coordinates of the third point as $(7.66, 0)$.

Is that what it means to solve this problems?

Comment: It works, thanks. Somehow that didn't come to mind.